# How to Rank Text search in Postgresql using multiple keywords where all keywords present should be ranked highest

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ranking

I have this condition of full text search using multiple keywords - say `Education, Healthcare, Nutrition`. They are joined using `or`.

Now I want to have the search result rank in such a way that if any search result contains all the keywords would rank higher than those which have any two keywords. That is the search results containing `Education, Healthcare, Nutrition` would be higher ranked than those containing `Education, Healthcare` or `Education, Nutrition` or `Healthcare, Nutrition`.

Similarly those results containing any two keywords, would be ranked higher than those having just one keyword. In other words the search results containing only `Education, Healthcare` or `Education, Nutrition` or `Healthcare, Nutrition` would be ranked higher than those containing only `Education` or `Nutrition` or `Healthcare`.

The table column which is being used for search is of type `tsquery` and the search string is being converted to `tsvector` datatype in the search query.

I have tried using `ts_rank` and `ts_rank_cd` function altering the `weights` and `normalization` parameters but with not much benefit. If anyone could suggest me a way on how these can be used to achieve the above stated goals or any other way to attain the same goals, it would be very helpful.

**Edit After jjanes' comment**

Here in my case I am searching the text in articles. So an article basically contains multiple occurrences of any single keyword. So, taking my example above, if a result has each the keywords `Education, Healthcare, Nutrition` appear twice in an article would be ranked lower than a result where only keywords `Education, Healthcare` appear 4 times each.

I hope this clears the confusion as stated by @jjanes.

Comment: In my hands the two argument form of ts_rank does what you want.  Can you provide a concrete example of it not?

Comment: @jjanes I have updated the question to address your point

Comment: Still can't reproduce.  I still get the doc with all three words twice ranked higher than the one with two words four times each.

Comment: @Blip Have you got the solution for this? I have a same requirement and struggling to find the solution.